# Updating PHP from 5.6 to 7.2 crashes website (compatibility issues)

Tags: php

So *One* automatically updated our PHP version to 7.2 but there are some compatibility issues that came with it. I have downgraded it to 5.6 for now. I have some PHP experience but I have never done anything like this before. I have read that autoload is no longer used, so that must be fixed. Are there any tutorials on this subject that would help me get the page running? I have tried searching for answers but I don't know what is relevant and what isn't.

Here are all the warnings I got when I loaded the page with 7.2!

> Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /lib/vendor/dompdf/
>   include/autoload.inc.php on line 83 
> Warning: Declaration of ActiveRecord\DateTime::setTime($hour, $minute, $second = NULL) should be compatible with 
>   DateTime::setTime($hour, $minute, $second = NULL, $microseconds = NULL) in /lib/vendor/
>   PHP-ActiveRecord/lib/DateTime.php on line 150 Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of 
>   PHP; PasswordHash has a deprecated constructor in /lib/vendor/PasswordHash.php on line 27 
> Warning: 
>   ini_set(): Cannot change zlib.output_compression - headers already sent in /config/Config.php on line 
>   9 Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /index.php on line 81 
>   Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /lib/vendor/
>   PHP-ActiveRecord/lib/Model.php on line 1587

Comment: You have to upgrade your dependencies in your composer.json file, too. It seems some of them use deprecated code.

Comment: You should follow the migration guides, http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php then http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.php and finally http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.php

Comment: Also, you must check if your dependencies are compatible with php@7 within your composer.json. If not, it may mean upgrading or replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are seeing are some warnings and some follow up errors.

The `__autoload` function will be removed in a future PHP version.
You could deactivate deprecation warnings with something like

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);
```

But I would advise against it and rather fix the problems and use `spl_autoload_register` instead just like php tells you too.

```
Warning: Declaration of ActiveRecord\DateTime::setTime($hour, $minute, $second = NULL) should be compatible with DateTime::setTime($hour, $minute, $second = NULL, $microseconds = NULL) in /lib/vendor/ PHP-ActiveRecord/lib/DateTime.php on line 150
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; PasswordHash has a deprecated constructor in /lib/vendor/PasswordHash.php on line 27
```

Those hint to actual problems in some vendor code, you might want to use composer to update the dependencies to a current version if possible.

```
Warning: ini_set(): Cannot change zlib.output_compression - headers already sent in /config/Config.php on line 9 
Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /index.php on line 81
```

Those are follow up errors because of the error output itself. If you fix the problems above those should disappear.

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /lib/vendor/ PHP-ActiveRecord/lib/Model.php on line 1587
```

This one could be a follow up error as well, but PHP7 got a bit more strict so you should check if you really provide an array to `count` first.

Here is a list of breaking changes in PHP7
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php